# Encoding in oracle apex when uploading documents in CSV format

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, export-to-csv

Oracle Apex Product Build 18.2.0.00.12.
I created a page with the type "interactive report" and when I click on the report page "Action - Download" I choose CSV-format.
The file is downloaded in CSV format.
When opening a file, "їїїї" is displayed instead of Cyrillic characters.

How can this problem be solved if the data in the report itself is displayed correctly in Cyrillic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Shared Components => Application Definition Attributes => Globalization and change Automatic CSV encoding setting to 'Yes'.

It could also be that the application you use to view the exported CSV file doesn't support Cyrillic, I sugggest also make sure that it does.

Comment: Thank you very much, changing the Automatic CSV Encoding parameter by setting the parameter to NO really helped.
Uploading to CSV still happens in the wrong encoding, but now I can change the encoding in EXCEL and get the desired column to cirillic)